# Can´t access google cloud storage with service account. Service account does not have storage.objects.list access

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-play-console, service-accounts

I want to access Goolge play reports on the command line with gsutil and a service account. There is a Cloud Storage URI for that with the form *gs://bucket_name*, and I can list and download reports with my user account but not with the service account I created. The error is always the same:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 "service-account-name" does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I have asign all the required permissions to the service account, so I do not understand why with the user account works and fails with the service account.

[image]

So if you know how to help me, i will thank you a lot.

Comment: I have tried at my end and I was able to list objects in a bucket only with the Storage Object Admin role, it seems like your Service Account it has not taken the changes. If you run this command "gcloud projects get-iam-policy <YOUR GCLOUD PROJECT> --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:<YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT>"" what do you get?

Comment: You should get both roles (Owner and Storage Object Admin role).

Comment: @SamuelRomero, hi thanks for replying. I try the command and it correctly output that my service account have ´roles/owner´ and ´roles/storage.objectAdmin´. To put you in context, Im trying to access a bucket not created by me. This bucket is automatically created with reports from Google Play (I don't know if this has something to do), and i can list them and download them with my google play account but I can´t do the same with the service account despite it have the same roles.

Comment: Got it now. I have a couple of questions. You mention the bucket was automatically created with the reports from Google Play, right? If you go to the console and look for the bucket's name you mentioned, do you see it? If not, How do you access it with your Google Play account?

Comment: Hi there. I have the same issue, I tried setting both roles to my service account (wich is linked to my app in play console) but I still get the same error (`does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket`)

Comment: @SamuelRomero, when I go to the google storage console there is no bucket listed, although the project is shown. I dont know if the fact that this reports are automatically created by google play works different and that is why I can access them with the gmail account and it can´t be access with a service account.

Comment: And regarding how I download them, with commands using `gsutil cp source dest` and in the google play console in the reports page directly downloading the csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Storage buckets will only appear in the developer console under the project that they were created with.  This bucket was not created under the project you have permissions, so it won't appear in any list in the developers console for you.

In order to grant access to the service account that you created, you can just add it as an additional user to the console with read-only permissions, which will give that service account access to the bucket. For more information about this matter, please follow [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844686?hl=en&visit_id=637485712010564729-1982968354&rd=1) Help Center article.

Something to keep in mind is that depends on the task you want to accomplish, it could be necessary to add more roles to the Service Account. For example, if you want to view financial data, may be you need a "Financial" role for the SA.